# ElasticSearch REST API Aggregating Text Field

Tags: elasticsearch, curl, kibana

So I'm brand new to ElasticSearch/Kibana, trying to create a simple Curl command to hit Elastic's REST API and return the number of logs that contain a given string of text. But I'm getting the following error:

"Text fields are not optimised for operations that require per-document field data like aggregations and sorting, so these operations are disabled by default. Please use a keyword field instead. Alternatively, set fielddata=true on [timestamp] in order to load field data by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can use significant memory."

My code is as follows:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "timestamp": {
        "gte": "2021-06-15",
        "lte": "2021-06-23"
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "hit_count_per_day": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "timestamp",
        "calendar_interval": "day"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Where should I be adding this "fielddata=true" value mentioned in the error? Can anyone point me towards a reference doc for ElasticSearch API syntax?

Comment: can you please share your index mapping ?

Comment: @ESCoder I'm not sure about the index mapping -- I'm using a search that was created by someone else.
The index pattern is c0001_log-*

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error you are getting, it seems that `timestamp` field is of `text` type. You cannot perform aggregation on `text` type fields.
Since you are using `date_histogram` aggregation, you should use`timestamp` field to be of `date` type.

Modify your index mapping as shown below

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "timestamp": {
        "type": "date"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Phil Clelland please go through the answer, and let me know if this resolved your issue ?

Comment: Sorry @ESCoder I was getting parsing errors. Really not sure where to define the mappings in the query; I'm coding blind here without any syntax guidelines.